# Mapbox elevation data precision

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've created a simple three.js app which renders map tiles in 3D. Each tile is a separated mesh (a plane with 10 height and 10 width segments) which uses a `THREE.ShaderMaterial`. In order to access elevation data I used this [Mapbox tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/). Two png tiles (elevation and color) are passed to the simple shader that decodes height value:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
uniform sampler2D bump;
uniform sampler2D map;

varying float vAmount;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main()
{
    vUv = uv;
    vec4 bumpData = texture2D( bump, uv );
    vAmount = bumpData.x;

    float height = (-0.4 + (bumpData.x * 256.0 * 256.0 + bumpData.y * 256.0 + bumpData.z)/1024.0);

    vec3 newPosition = position;
    newPosition.z = height;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );
}
</script>
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
uniform sampler2D bump;
uniform sampler2D map;

varying vec2 vUv;

varying float vAmount;

void main()
{
    if(vAmount == 0.0) {
        discard;
    }

    vec4 tile = texture2D(map, vUv);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + tile;
}
</script>
```

[image: screenshot]
However, it seems like nearby tiles have a bit different height values on edges. I've tried to use `THREE.NearestFilter` for textures but it didn't have any effect. Is there a way to get rid of these white stripes?

Comment: The white lines could be caused by a number of reasons. Maybe the vertices don't exactly align? Or maybe the texture has a white edge? But it's most likely because you're doing `if(vAmount == 0.0){discard;}` You should provide a live example to confirm.

Comment: @Marquizzo This line does not affect white lines. It just doesn't render mesh if elevation tile is not loaded.
If you look on the tiles from the top they seem to be perfectly aligned, but when you watch from other angles you can see that geometry have different height and small white gaps between them.

Comment: It's hard to provide a definitive answer without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I'm just speculating, but it's probably because there's no interpolation between edge vertices. If one edge is at height 78, and the next tile is at height 79, you'll see a gap of 1 unit along that edge. It's like it's creating a "step". You don't see that along the face of the tile because those vertices are connected and make smooth transitions.

Comment: @Marquizzo You must be right. So the only way to connect all nearby meshes is to pass 9 height tiles (the main one and 8 neighbours) to the shader and interpolate them on edges?

Comment: That *could* work, but maybe you could do one big tile instead of multiple small ones, to avoid 9-way texture lookups. You could combine all the mapbox data into a single texture by drawing it as a grid on a canvas via [`.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). Of course, that depends on the functionality of your project, it wouldn't work if you want to implement endless scrolling.

Comment: @Marquizzo The map is endless so it wouldn't work. If 9 textures is too much maybe I can use only 4 (the main tile, the one on the right side, the one on the bottom and the one between them, so that they form a 2x2 rectangle).